Tab-completion not working in 'prlctl enter' container on Mac with Parallel's Desktop
I've written some code to give my Mac users a console into their Parallel's Desktop VM in order to run our Node JS framework. The code essentially finds their running Windows VM and uses 'prlctl enter --current-user' in order to give them a console right within their Terminal. This works great except for one real annoying problem. Inside that console, TAB Completion does not work :)
So if they want to CD over to C:\Temp, typing out 'cd te' followed by TAB, does not completion the directory as it would natively inside that Windows VM. I'm assuming that this is a known "bug". Any info would be great as other than this, the console really works great for our needs.
Thanks!
